# Using the same ArrayAdapter in different Activities?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-arrayadapter

Is it possible to use the same ArrayAdapter in different Activities?

Comment: depends what you mean by same but I'm gonna go with yes, reusing code is a fundamental design technique in programming

Comment: what you want to achieve exactly by this?

Comment: @Man It is an exam question I found somewhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's possible but why?
you can create an instance of your class in your activities
and java's GC (garbage collector) will remove unused object from RAM

by the way you can use code like this to reach to what you want

```
public MyArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter{
    private static MyArrayAdapeter instance;
    public MyArrayAdapter getInstance(){
        if(instance==null) instance = new MyArrayAdapter();
        return instance;
    }
}
```

or simply use static variable and assign your object to it and access to it with your class